# Remove duplicate values in the same column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.0

I want to remove duplicate values from the same string in a single column.

For examples sake say we have `TableA` which has a single field `FieldA`.

**Sample Data**

```
FieldA
red blue pink purple green green green yellow pink purple blue blue blue
```

**Expected Output**

```
FieldA
red blue pink purple green yellow
```

Comment: Observation: horrible schema, I hope you feel suitably embarrassed having to share it. Question 1: does the order of string tokens matter? Question 2: is splitting on space going to give you valid tokens?

Comment: Its clearly a sample piece and not a real schema....

Comment: You either have repeated tokens stored as one big string of text or you don't. If you don't then I'm not sure what your question is asking. You'll need to respond to the 2 questions in my comment if anyone is going to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should imho fix your schema, your current schema will cause many more issues, not just this one.

But to answer the question, you could use some array functions:

```
SELECT  array_to_string(array_agg( distinct content), ' ')
FROM    unnest(string_to_array('red blue pink purple green green green yellow pink purple blue blue blue',' ')) u(content);
```